# Double type value in English locale

Tags: c#

I have a line of code for string formatting like below -

```
double dVal = Convert.ToDouble(args[0], 
                              System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
string result = string.Format("{0}", dVal);
```

Now in other locales (like German and French), the `result` string contains "," instead of "." Which is expected behavior.

Is there something I could add by which I will maintain my double value with its "." and not containing ","?

Comment: What do you mean by `maintain my double value` ? do you want to parse only those strings which contains `.` and ignore the one that contains `,` ?

Comment: Yes , something like that cause later on in my project I use this string in my unmanaged C++ project where I get multiple failures if string contains "," instead of ".". so I want string format or some additional line of code should make result value doubel having "." in all locale. , Is it possible??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the current [NumberFormatInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numberdecimalseparator.aspx) object to set the decimal seperator explicitely to the seperator of your needs.

Something like that should do the trick:

```
double dVal = Convert.ToDouble(args[0],
                                  System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

var nfi = NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.Clone() as NumberFormatInfo;
nfi.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";

string result = string.Format(nfi, "{0}", dVal);
```

Note that you have to clone the `NumberFormatInfo` since the properties are read-only.

Comment: +1 Useful suggestion explaining sortof inner working of the formatting. Also in this particular case simply passing InvariantCulture (as Joey suggested) would be enough.

Answer (score 1):

Use an English culture explicitly when formatting the string. If you require it for roundtripping with other applications that parse the string, then use the Invariant culture, just as you did with parsing already.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use `String.Replace` as it won't care if it does not contain ','

```
double dVal = Convert.ToDouble(args[0], System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
string result =  dVal.ToString().Replace(',','.');
```

Not the best solution, but quick and easy :)

Comment: Not -1 only because it is clearly a joke... What would happen if value contains both deciaml separator and group separator like "1,234.45" (or other way around 1.234,45")?

Comment: How on earth do you add group seperators to a floating-point number

Comment: `(1234.01).ToString("N", new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("es-es"))` produces "1.234,01"...

Comment: but that not in my answer, I know a String can contain group seperators, but a double cant

Comment: So after `Replace` formatted string will contain 2 dots like "1.234.01"... I don't think it would be very useful...

Comment: surely you would just replace before formatting, aggg never mind.